# Macbook Pro 2018 (Mojave) - No WiFi hardware installed

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, touch-bar, touch-id

My wifi stop working and it display "No hardware installed" message on my Macbook Pro 2018. I've tried reset NVRAM and SMC but no luck. In system rapport it looks installed, on en0 BSD. Also i've tried to remove NetworkInterfaces.plist.

[image]

Ps: i have an MINIX NEO C adapter and since i've used that i had this problem. First time it started to work bi itself, but second time don't want to start anymore.

Comment: Please do not use tag `mac-pro` for questions about MacBook Pro.

Comment: Ok, but what is stand for tag `mac-pro` for? @GEdgar

Comment: That tag is for the "Mac Pro" ... see https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/

Comment: Note: tag `macbookpro` automaticaly changes to `macbook`.  So I guess that is the proper tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like wasn't a software problem, was a hardware one. Apple replaced my motherboard and touch-id. Now the WiFi is working. A little bit disappointed for my first Apple product.